# Python TCP client and server sockets program not properly decoding message

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am jumping back into a networking course that uses python which i am out of practise with.

Currently I have the program working fully how i want it to just minus that it wont remove all the weird symbols in my text file.
I read online that the file indicates it isnt being properly converted from byte format. However, I did try using codecs to decode it that way and the response I got was it received a str when expecting a byte object.

The current code below does not give that error but no matter how I alter my code I keep being unable to have the text file displayed with tabs and new lines and without the non-human readable code within the file.

Any clarification and expansion on my lack of understanding is appreciated.

server file

```
import sys
import argparse
import os

host = 'localhost'
data_buff = 2048

def TCPserver1(port):
    # socket from server
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_address = (host, port)
    print('Server listening...')
    # socket binding to the server address
    sock.bind(server_address)
    # server listening for incoming connections
    sock.listen(5)  # Increased backlog for more connections

    def check_file_existence(file_name):
        current_directory = os.getcwd()
        file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, file_name)
        return file_path if os.path.exists(file_path) else None

    while True:
        print("Waiting for connection...")
        client, address = sock.accept()
        print(f"Got connection from {address}")
        file_name = client.recv(data_buff).decode('utf-8')
        print(f"Server received the file name '{file_name}'")

        file_path = check_file_existence(file_name)

        if file_path:
            client.send(b"Sent\n")
            file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
            client.send(str(file_size).encode('utf-8'))
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
                file_data = file.read(data_buff)
                while file_data:
                    client.send(file_data)
                    file_data = file.read(data_buff)
            print("Done sending.")
        else:
            client.send(b"File not found")

        client.close()
        print("Connection is closed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='File Transfer Server')
    parser.add_argument('--port', action="store", dest="port", type=int, required=True)
    given_args = parser.parse_args()
    port = given_args.port
    TCPserver1(port)
```

client file

```
import sys
import argparse
import codecs

host = 'localhost'

def clean_text(data):
    # Replace non-standard line breaks with '\n'
    cleaned_data = data.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n')
    return cleaned_data

def TCPClient1(port, file_name):
    # socket from client
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = (host, port)
    print("Connecting to %s port %s" % server_address)
    sock.connect(server_address)
    try:
        print("file opened.")
        print("sending data...")
        sock.sendall(file_name.encode('utf-8'))
        print("receiving data...")
        response = sock.recv(1024)
        if response == b"Sent\n":
            file_size = int(sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
            file_data = b""
            bytes_received = 0
            while bytes_received < file_size:
                data = sock.recv(1024)
                bytes_received += len(data)
                file_data += data

            # decoded_data = file_data.decode('utf-8')  # Decode the received data
            # cleaned_data = clean_text(decoded_data)
            cleaned_data = codecs.decode(file_data)
            print(cleaned_data)  # Print the cleaned data only
            print("Successfully got the file")
        else:
            print("File not found on the server")
    except socket.error as e:
        print("Socket error: %s" % str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Other exception: %s" % str(e))
    finally:
        print("Connection is closed")
        sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='File Transfer Client')
    parser.add_argument('--port', action="store", dest="port", type=int, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--file', action="store", dest="file", type=str, required=True)
    given_args = parser.parse_args()
    port = given_args.port
    file_name = given_args.file
    TCPClient1(port, file_name)
```

the text.txt file contains

```
b'First line\r\n\r\n\xe2\x80\x9cNo. Look.\xe2\x80\x9d He shared the app in his smart glasses with the
car\xe2\x80\x99s dashboard screen. \r\nThe big rectangle lit up with a map of Toronto; the
city\xe2\x80\x99s jumbled, almost logical grid of streets was overlaid with coloured swatches. \r\nIt
almost looked like a traffic app, but instead of congestion it showed security-camera and neighbourhoodwatch coverage.\r\n\r\n\xe2\x80\x9cSee those?\xe2\x80\x9d He pointed at a rash of little red dots strewn
across the map. \xe2\x80\x9cThose are police cruisers, and the little triangles are drones. \r\nGod, I love
crowd-sourcing.\xe2\x80\x9d\r\n\r\nPalassio smiled, framing the screen with his hands in case the planner
had been looking. \xe2\x80\x9cYou fucked with the wrong people, jackass.\xe2\x80\x9d\r\n\r\nThe car
was driving, so he had the luxury of turning to contemplate the distant city lights off to the left. \r\nPast
the muted tones of the forested Don Valley, downtown was a milling crowd of glittering giants extending
\r\nfrom the lake to the indefinite boundaries of North York up ahead. Toronto was a beautiful city;
maybe, \r\n'
Sent b'if he wasn\xe2\x80\x99t here for work, he might have considered settling. Along with four million
other people? He laughed and shook his head.\r\n\r\nAnyway, you never live where you work. Not if
you\xe2\x80\x99re in the Profession.\r\n\r\n\xe2\x80\x9cWe should take the next right,\xe2\x80\x9d said
Hansen. \xe2\x80\x9cCop coming down the hill.\xe2\x80\x9d\r\n\r\nEND of file'
```

Comment: What does "... i want it to just minus that it wont remove all the weird symbols in my text file..." mean? Are you saying that you only want the ASCII characters from the file? i.e., those with *ord()* values less than 128

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to eliminate extended ASCII characters from a bytes object.

You could do it like this:

```
with open("foo.txt", "rb") as data:
    buffer = bytes(filter(lambda c: c < 128, data.read()))
```